# Linux' `ps f` (tree view) equivalent on OSX?

Tags: command-line, compatibility, unix

How can I get a tree view like the one below on OSX?

```
vartec@some_server:~$ ps xf
PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
11519 ?        S      0:00 sshd: vartec@pts/0
11520 pts/0    Ss     0:00  \_ -bash
11528 pts/0    R+     0:00      \_ ps xf
```

To clarify, I'm mostly interested in the tree structure, not the extended information.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You can install the `pstree` command using either [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (my personal favourite), [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or [Fink](https://www.finkproject.org/) and you'll get a command-line, tree view of processes on your Mac.

With Homebrew installed, just run:

```
brew install pstree
```

then use it like `pstree` from the command line.

Comment: That pstree seems to be "lightly" maintained, last commit was Aug 2022. For a modern, popular, well maintained alternative see [my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/469056/317236).

Answer (score 27):

The below small perl script I've called 'treeps' that should do exactly that; works on linux (Sci Linux 6) + OSX (10.6, 10.9)

Example output:

```
$ ./treeps
    |_ 1        /sbin/launchd
        |_ 10       /usr/libexec/kextd
        |_ 11       /usr/sbin/DirectoryService
        |_ 12       /usr/sbin/notifyd
        |_ 118      /usr/sbin/coreaudiod
        |_ 123      /sbin/launchd
    [..]
           |_ 157      /Library/Printers/hp/hpio/HP Device [..]
           |_ 172      /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app [..]
              |_ 174      login -pf acct
                 |_ 175      -tcsh
                    |_ 38571    su - erco
                       |_ 38574    -tcsh
```

Here's the code..

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# treeps -- show ps(1) as process hierarchy -- v1.0 erco@seriss.com 07/08/14
my %p; # Global array of pid info
sub PrintLineage($$) {    # Print proc lineage
  my ($pid, $indent) = @_;
  printf("%s |_ %-8d %s\n", $indent, $pid, $p{$pid}{cmd}); # print
  foreach my $kpid (sort {$a<=>$b} @{ $p{$pid}{kids} } ) {  # loop thru kids
    PrintLineage($kpid, "   $indent");                       # Recurse into kids
  }
}
# MAIN
open(FD, "ps axo ppid,pid,command|");
while ( <FD> ) { # Read lines of output
  my ($ppid,$pid,$cmd) = ( $_ =~ m/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s(.*)/ );  # parse ps(1) lines
  $p{$pid}{cmd} = $cmd;
  # $p{$pid}{kids} = (); <- this line is not needed and can cause incorrect output
  push(@{ $p{$ppid}{kids} }, $pid); # Add our pid to parent's kid
}
PrintLineage(($ARGV[0]) ? $ARGV[0] : 1, "");     # recurse to print lineage starting with specified PID or PID 1.
```

Comment: I found this answer useful in a situation where I couldn't install Brew yet (debugging Packer+vmware issues).

Comment: This is a great answer and a great starting point as well, but it would be more useful if there was a way to truncate lines, as they get really, really long in OSX and wrap inside the terminal window. Any ideas about this?

Comment: @Rolf `treeps | cut -c 1-$COLUMNS` will cut the long lines off at the width of your current terminal window.  (or a simple number like `100` instead of the `$COLUMNS` variable)

Comment: similar to Amos Shapira's situation, what has me looking for this is `brew` itself -- taking a long time to update, and not telling me anything in the terminal where it is running; so, for me, this answer is a gem!

Answer (score 20):

Another option is `htop`, which has an option to display in tree format. You can either press `F5` interactively, or use `htop -t` when launching it. To install: `brew install htop`

[image]

Source: [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/324945/what-is-the-os-x-bsd-equivalent-of-the-gnu-ps-auxf-command/627665#627665)

Answer (score 12):

I adapted Greg Ercolano's perl script to python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import subprocess as subp
import os.path
import sys
import re
from collections import defaultdict

def psaxo():
    cmd = ['ps', 'axo', 'ppid,pid,comm']
    proc = subp.Popen(cmd, stdout=subp.PIPE)
    proc.stdout.readline()
    for line in proc.stdout:
        yield line.rstrip().split(None,2)

def hieraPrint(pidpool, pid, prefix=''):
    if os.path.exists(pidpool[pid]['cmd']):
        pname = os.path.basename(pidpool[pid]['cmd'])
    else:
        pname = pidpool[pid]['cmd']
    ppid = pidpool[pid]['ppid']
    pppid = pidpool[ppid]['ppid']
    try:
        if pidpool[pppid]['children'][-1] == ppid:
            prefix = re.sub(r'^(\s+\|.+)[\|`](\s+\|- )$', '\g<1> \g<2>', prefix)
    except IndexError:
        pass
    try:
        if pidpool[ppid]['children'][-1] == pid:
            prefix = re.sub(r'\|- $', '`- ', prefix)
    except IndexError:
        pass
    sys.stdout.write('{0}{1}({2}){3}'.format(prefix,pname,pid, os.linesep))
    if len(pidpool[pid]['children']):
        prefix = prefix.replace('-', ' ')
        for idx,spid in enumerate(pidpool[pid]['children']):
            hieraPrint(pidpool, spid, prefix+' |- ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pidpool = defaultdict(lambda:{"cmd":"", "children":[], 'ppid':None})
    for ppid,pid,command in psaxo():
        ppid = int(ppid)
        pid  = int(pid)
        pidpool[pid]["cmd"] = command
        pidpool[pid]['ppid'] = ppid
        pidpool[ppid]['children'].append(pid)

    hieraPrint(pidpool, 1, '')
```

Example output:

```
launchd(1)
 |- syslogd(38)
 |- UserEventAgent(39)
 |- kextd(41)
 |- fseventsd(42)
 |- thermald(44)
 |- appleeventsd(46)
...
 |- iTerm(2879)
 |   |- login(2883)
 |   |   `- -bash(2884)
 |   |       `- Python(17781)
 |   |           `- ps(17782)
 |   |- login(7091)
 |   |   `- -bash(7092)
 |   |       `- ssh(7107)
 |   `- login(7448)
 |       `- -bash(7449)
 |           `- bash(9040)
 |               `- python(9041)
 |- installd(2909)
 |- DataDetectorsDynamicData(3867)
 |- netbiosd(3990)
 |- firefox(5026)
...
```

Answer (score 5):

I made a different script that takes (should take?) all the arguments you can normally give to "ps" on OSX:

https://github.com/jhthorsen/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/ps

Example output:

```
$ ps Af
   PID TTY      STAT      TIME COMMAND
     1 ??       Ss   198:44.08 /sbin/launchd
   141 ??       Ss     2:40.76   \_ /usr/sbin/syslogd
   142 ??       Ss     6:54.11   \_ /usr/libexec/UserEventAgent (System)
   145 ??       Ss     0:32.48   \_ /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Uninstall.framework/Resources/uninstalld
   146 ??       Ss     1:12.84   \_ /usr/libexec/kextd
   147 ??       Ss    18:51.47   \_ /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.f
   148 ??       Ss     0:14.31   \_ /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/Support/mediaremoted
   151 ??       Ss    59:43.39   \_ /usr/sbin/systemstats --daemon
   441 ??       S      0:05.39       \_ /usr/sbin/systemstats --logger-helper /private/var/db/systemstats
...

> ps Af -o ppid,pid,cpu,command
  PPID   PID CPU COMMAND
     0     1   0 /sbin/launchd
     1   141   0   \_ /usr/sbin/syslogd
     1   142   0   \_ /usr/libexec/UserEventAgent (System)
     1   145   0   \_ /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Uninstall.framework/Resources/uninstalld
     1   146   0   \_ /usr/libexec/kextd
     1   147   0   \_ /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versi
     1   148   0   \_ /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/Support/mediaremoted
     1   151   0   \_ /usr/sbin/systemstats --daemon
   151   441   0       \_ /usr/sbin/systemstats --logger-helper /private/var/db/systemstats
```

Answer (score 1):

[`procs`](https://github.com/dalance/procs) has a flag to see processes in a tree shape:

```bash
procs --tree
```

Also colors

[image]

Installing with Homebrew is:

```bash
brew install procs
```

Comment: Followed your comment from another forum. Love the colors!