# top, group by command

Tags: macos, command-line

Is it possible to run `top` and group processes by `COMMAND`?
Seeing every single individual Chrome process not very helpful

```
PID                     COMMAND                           %CPU                  MEM
0                       kernel_task                       2.5                   1219M
82793-                  Google Chrome He                  0.0                   427M
15051-                  Google Chrome He                  5.3                   308M+
82557-                  Google Chrome                     7.1                   285M-
14398-                  Google Chrome He                  0.1                   253M-
14580-                  Google Chrome He                  0.1                   250M+
90                      WindowServer                      1.8                   218M-
82626-                  Google Chrome He                  23.1                  194M-
82666-                  Google Chrome He                  0.2                   191M-
86580-                  Google Chrome He                  0.7                   171M-
14596-                  Google Chrome He                  0.5                   164M-
82630-                  Google Chrome He                  1.0                   141M-
82633-                  Google Chrome He                  0.1                   135M-
82622-                  Google Chrome He                  0.5                   134M-
14592-                  Google Chrome He                  0.4                   131M+
82632-                  Google Chrome He                  0.2                   130M+
82663-                  Google Chrome He                  0.4                   130M-
82623-                  Google Chrome He                  0.4                   124M-
82621-                  Google Chrome He                  0.5                   119M-
```

Comment: Can you use `atop`? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/441760/59808

Answer (score 1):

The key function of `top` is to offer a life view of all processes in the system, sorted by whatever option you choose. As Chrome spawns several processes (one per tab), they all will be shown (same happens with Safari/Webkit actually).

As an alternative you can install `pstree` (see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/11806/9058) for installation instructions) which displays the process hierarchy (but doesn't offer live updating).