What steps can I take to track down what is trying to gain sudo access?
I now have a prompt that recurs every 30s wanting me to allow running some unknown sudo script.
The prompt is a macos builtin prompt that takes the center of the screen and can lose focus but can't be moved or minimized. It is what you would expect to get if you ran something like sudo htop on the command line.
Specifically it reads:

sudo is trying to execute a command as administrator.
Touch ID or enter your password to allow this.


Obviously I'm not going to allow it because I don't know what it is. Hitting cancel works, but it pops back up 30s later.
Is there any way to track down what program is causing it?
If it matters at all, this is an M2 running Sonoma 14.5
Seems like this questions

The prompt is obviously coming from a background task that runs a shell script as root, but is not itself running as root. You may be able to figure out what it is by going through your login items. If not, examine the output of this command: sudo sfltool dumpbtm

Display the process tree, that will tell you what invoked sudo, although it may just lead you back to a shell.  macOS doesn't make that terribly easy by default, several solutions are here... https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11770/linux-ps-f-tree-view-equivalent-on-osx.  I use pstree from MacPorts.
